# Show that the ring of polynomials $k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ is an integral extension of the ring of symmetric polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

> I want to prove that $A= k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$, where $k$ is a field, is an integral extension of the subring $B$ consisting of the symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables.

It is sufficient by finding an expression with coefficients in B that nulls when evaluated the variables $x_{i}$ for every $i=1,...,n$. I tried it but I can’t find a suitable polynomial the satisfies this. Some help?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo and I have corrected it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the polynomial $p_n=(t-x_1)\dots(t-x_n)\in A[t]$. Clearly any permutation of the $x_i$ will leave $p_n$ unchanged, so every coefficient of $p_n$ must lie in $B$, and hence $p_n\in B[t]$. On the other hand, $p_n(x_i)=0$ for any $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, so $p_n$ is the desired monic polynomial satisfied by each $x_i$.

Comment: In order words, $p_n = t^n - s_1 t^{n-1} + s_2 t^{n-2} - \cdots + (-1)^n s_n$ where $s_i$ is the $i$th symmetric polynomial in $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, i.e. $s_1 = x_1 + \cdots + x_n$, $s_2 = \sum_{i < j} x_i x_j$, $\ldots$, $s_n = x_1 \cdots x_n$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler indeed! but I feel it's perhaps slightly clearer to see that each $x_i$ is a root when it's not written in the expanded form

Comment: And more generally, the same sort of argument shows directly that for any $q \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, $\prod_{\sigma \in S_n} (t - \sigma(q)) \in B[t]$ is monic and has $q$ as a root - where $S_n$ acts on $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ by permuting the variables accordingly.  (Not that it's technically needed, once you've shown each $x_i$ is in the integral closure of $B$ as this answer does; but it's somewhat nice to have this generalization.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler true, that's a nice explicit construction!

Answer (score 1):

This question may have interest for others visiting this site.

In fact the result is more general: If $H$ is any finite group acting on a commutative ring $A$ and if $A^H$ is the set of elements $a\in A$ with $ha=a$ for all $h\in H$
it follows $A^H \subseteq A$ is an integral extension of rings. Let $H:=\{h_1,..,h_n\}$
and let $a\in A$. Let

$f_a(t):=(t-h_1a)\cdots (t-h_na)\in A[T]$.

It follows

$hf_a(t)=(t-(hh_1)a)\cdots (t-(hh_n)a)=f_a(t)$

for any $h\in G$, since the element $h$ permutes the set $\{h_1,..,h_n\}$. Hence $f_a(t)\in A^H[t]$. The polynomial
$f_a(t)$ is monic and $f_a(a)=0$ since there is an $i$ with $h_ia=ea=a$. Hence $a$ is integral over $A^H$ for any $a\in A$.

Question: "It is sufficient to find an expression with coefficients in B that is zero when evaluated in the variables $x_i$ for every $i=1,...,n$. I tried it, but I can’t find a suitable polynomial that satisfies this. Some help?"

Answer: The polynomial $f_a(t)$ defined above gives a general answer to your question for an arbitrary finite group $H$ and commutative unital ring $A$.

Example: Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ elements and let $k:=\mathbb{Z}$ be the ring of integers. Let

$S_n:=\{\sigma_1,..,\sigma_l\}$

and let $a(x_1,..,x_n)\in A:=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,..,x_n].$

Define

$f_a(t):=(t-\sigma_1a)\cdots (t-\sigma_la) \in B:=A^{S_n}[t]$.

It follows by the above argument that $f_a(t)$ is a monic polynomial and that $f_a(a)=0$. Hence the result is true over the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$:
The ring extension

$\mathbb{Z}[x_1,..,x_n]^{S_n} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x_1,..,x_n]$

is an integral extension.

Comment: Comment: I changed from "g" to "h" to avoid this post being "deleted".